# Cython tree data structure with numpy array as value

Tags: cython

I am implementing a board game engine. To speed up the search I started looking into migrating some parts to Cython. A central (recursive) data structure in the algorithm is a tree node, which points to its parent and its 0..N children. The node has several values, but the one relevant to my question is an `np.ndarray` of move probabilities. In essence, I want sth like this:

```
cdef struct CNNode:
    CNNode* parent
    list[CNNode*] children
    float[:,:,:] probabilities  # Could also be np.ndarray, but that also yields an error.
```

But for `probabilities` Cython complains:

> C struct/union member cannot be a memory view

I also tried [Extension Types](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html), but those apparently don't support the recursive structure I need.

Is there a way to define the data structure I need in Cython? Thanks!

Comment: I really don't see why extension types wouldn't work. You would want to use `CNNode` instead of `CNNode*`

Comment: Thanks, David! You're right, extensions indeed do work: I ended up using 
`@cython.cclass
class CNN:
    _parent: Optional[CNN]
    _probs: Optional[np.ndarray]
    _children: np.ndarray`

Comment: I'd probably use a list rather than an `np.ndarray` for children. For a Python object dtype a 1D ndarray is basically the same structure as a list but higher overhead. But glad you got it to work